# FCM http notification send multiple notification in one json

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I would like to send 2 notification in the same call (I have a technical issue not allowing me to make 2 seperate http calls).
currently, my json looks like:

```
{ 
  "data":
  {
      "id": "123456",
  },
  "to" : "/topics/news"
}
```

I would like to sent to something like an array of notification with different data like:

```
[
    { 
      "data":
      {
          "id": "123456",
      },
      "to" : "/topics/news"
    },
    { 
      "data":
      {
          "id": "789",
      },
      "to" : "/topics/news2"
    }
]
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no feature to send multiple payloads inside a single request for FCM.